# Grouping over subclasses in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my EF-model I have a base-class *Report* and a set of subclasses for this. Assume that I want to ask EF to get all reports and group them by the subclass type.

Consider this code where I do this semi-manually:

```
   var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Report>>
    {
        {typeof (CommentReport).Name, ReportEntitiesContainer.Instance.Reports.OfType<CommentReport>()},
        {typeof (BlogPostReport).Name, ReportEntitiesContainer.Instance.Reports.OfType<BlogPostReport>()},
        {typeof (NewsItemReport).Name, ReportEntitiesContainer.Instance.Reports.OfType<NewsItemReport>()},
        {typeof (ThreadReport).Name, ReportEntitiesContainer.Instance.Reports.OfType<ThreadReport>()},
        {typeof (UserProfileReport).Name, ReportEntitiesContainer.Instance.Reports.OfType<UserProfileReport>()},
        {typeof (ImageReport).Name, ReportEntitiesContainer.Instance.Reports.OfType<ImageReport>()}
    };
```

Is there any way to express logic that understand that I want to achieve this kind of grouping and accomplishes that without me having to manually hard-code all the subclasses in the logic?

Clarification: The type of the key in the above example with the dictionary is not important. It could be the name or the type or whatever.

Clarification 2: The question is intended to if this can be done as an IQueryable, not by loading all the rows before the grouping. I understand that there is some mismatch with the above example.

Comment: You can use GroupBy method combined with typeof statement e.g.: ReportEntitiesContainer.Instance.Reports.GroupBy(x => typeof(x))

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo That does not compile, and EF does not understand GroupBy(x => x.GetType()) either. (Or rather, GetType does not map to any function on the database side)

Comment: ReportEntitiesContainer.Instance.Reports.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => typeof(x))
p.s. I believe doing the grouping on application-side (AsEnumerable) won't hurt the performance, you need to ensure it first though.

Comment: here's similar question, and as you can see, the answer also suggest the use of AsEnumerable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833263/entity-framework-inheritance-sort-group-by-type

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo Thanks for pointing me to the duplicate, I will flag this question as such.